# C++ Are new versions of every method in a template class created on every instantiation

Tags: c++, class, templates, instantiation

What I have is a class template which takes two parameters one the type name and the other a boolean which determines whether the class will throw an exception if an error is encountered.

MyClass.h:

```
template<typename T, bool signal>
class MyClass {

    // methods which do not use or reference signal
    void Method1(args) {
        // some really long and complex code
    }
    void Method2(args) {
        // some more really long and complex code
    }

    // the method which checks the value of signal
    void throwMethod() {
        if (signal) throw (some exception); // if statement optimized away at compile time
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyClass<int, true> instThrow;
    MyClass<int, false> instNoThrow;

    // do something
}
```

But not every method in this class throws an exception, in-fact it is only two functions which actually check the value of signal, the rest do not use or reference this parameter AT ALL. My question: is every single method (Method1, Method2) of the class template recreated for a new instantiation where only the signal parameter differs (as shown above) (not used by most methods) or is only throwMethod (which actually uses the parameter) recreated, if the former is the case then it will result in unnecessary duplicates of Method1 & Method2.

If it makes any difference my compiler is Apple LLVM compiler 3.0

Comment: _'Are new versions of every method in a template class created on every instantiation'_ Yes they are, for any instantiated signature variations, actually used. That's what makes SFINAE such a useful thing ...

Comment: SFINAE? I've heard of it before but not quite sure as to what it is or how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods are generated for each variation of type parameters used by yout code.  To avoid this you can create a base class that holds Method1 and Method2.  The base class would only have T as a template parameter and the class above would just inherit from it.

Comment: To be honest, that's what I was originally considering, creating a base class template with a virtual empty (non-abstract) member throwMethod, and creating a new class MyClassThrow which inherits from MyClass and simply overrides throwMethod to throw an exception.